# Rails 4.1.8 with Devise authentication solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm more then positive this is a error on my part as development works fine. When in production sign up seems to work as the user gets created, however; when redirected to the home page its like the session is lost as it doesn't give a flash notice and it acts as if your not signed in. Same thing happens when you sign in you don't get any errors and it redirects back to the home page with no flash and your not signed in. No errors in the logs. I was wondering if i missed some setting i should of added in production any help will be appreciated.

Things I've tried:

1)disable cache on rails in production

2)user.valid_for_authentication? and user.active_for_authentication? both return true against the user

3) set config.http_authenticatable = false

4)removed protect_from_forgery with: :exception

Environment:
Ruby 2.1.3
Rails 4.1.8
Apache 2.4.7
tried both Safari browser and Firefox

Edit #1

Using devise 3.4.1. Logins are successful and users are created in the DB.

Logging

`I, [2014-12-07T23:42:35.846892 #9326]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 76.183.166.48 at 2014-12-07 23:42:35 -0500
I, [2014-12-07T23:42:35.848778 #9326]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2014-12-07T23:42:35.848974 #9326]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9ClmimUYOjV+rcxml3SrOuN1sfklRp4ezEMKp3IJSuY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"joebob@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
D, [2014-12-07T23:42:35.855928 #9326] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'joebob@gmail.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2014-12-07T23:42:35.955418 #9326] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
D, [2014-12-07T23:42:35.961404 #9326] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 4  [["current_sign_in_at", "2014-12-08 04:42:35.953525"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2014-12-08 04:35:07.820782"], ["sign_in_count", 20], ["updated_at", "2014-12-08 04:42:35.955881"]]
D, [2014-12-07T23:42:36.064737 #9326] DEBUG -- :    (102.9ms)  commit transaction
I, [2014-12-07T23:42:36.071840 #9326]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://bob.com/
I, [2014-12-07T23:42:36.072272 #9326]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 223ms (ActiveRecord: 103.9ms)`

Update #2

Changed from apache2.4 to nginx and everything is working now. So it must be with my apache configuration. I will do some more digging into apache2

Comment: Try putting this on your homepage <%= Time.now %> and see if it changes as you reload the page. This shows whether your have a cache issue or not. Post what you find here.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson Time does update however i did notice it seems a little behind my local computer.

Comment: I sync'd the server time using (sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com) just to make sure that wasn't a issue. still same issue

Comment: Write more about how you're doing sign up, e.g. Devise, Sorcery, your own code, etc. Add code to log to the success of sign up (this is to verify that production logging is working). Do you see the new user created in the production DB? Can the new user sign in successfully?

Comment: Another note is to confirm there wasn't anything between my dev config and prod config i copied my development.rb file over my production.rb file and was able to produce the same results. The only other thing i can think of is apache/passenger is my only other difference. While on dev i'm using webrick

Comment: I believe I have the exact same issue. I'd hate to have to switch to nginx to fix. Yikes.